# asp.net deployment to shared hosting dotnet 2.0

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, deployment, hosting, shared

Using visual studio code on linux, everything is good on localhost.

Now I want to push the asp.net mvc site to my hosting environment.

I'm using visual studio code on mint linux.

project is asp.net mvc 5 with dotnet version 2.0

share hosting is with daily razor

How do you publish for shared hosting environment.

Comment: MVC 5 doesn't run on .NET 2.0 so you're wrong somewhere.

Comment: MVC 5 cant run on Linux. It seems that you need to purchase windows hosting.

Comment: @MarkSpencer Yes, it can, via Mono (without async support). Not that I'd recommend it. But MVC 5 definitely can't run on .NET 2.0. And it'd be difficult to develop it with Visual Studio Code.

Comment: @mason Yes, that's right, absolutely agree with you

Comment: Sorry my bad its dotnet core 2.0 that I'm running